Can I route audio from a macOS Safari PWA to specific speakers, different from my system default?
I'm using a Progressive Web App (PWA) in Safari on macOS. I hope to select a specific audio output device for this PWA, separate from my system-wide audio settings.
Can I route audio from a macOS Safari PWA to specific speakers, different from my system default?

Would you share a link to this PWA? Maybe someone knows how it works or would look at the code and assist.

I thought Safari’s PWAs are hard coded and can’t be adjusted accordingly

Not at all, you can use any of these to test what the two answers attempt to provide you with sound. https://www.simicart.com/blog/progressive-web-apps-examples/

It is Google Meet and other PWA applications... I hope that you can help me know how to solve this on my own, so I can adjust the PWA code...

Rogue Amoeba's SoundSource can re-route Safari's output to another device, separate from the device the system is using.  Add Safari to the list of applications in SoundSource, and then choose an output destination.


This may be possible natively on several shipping and past macOS release versions of Safari.
You will need to enable a testable feature flag in Safari and then see if your media in your web app is coded in such a way to allow speaker selection.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-developer-tools/feature-flag-settings


My screen shot shows enabling the one flag I believe you should start by enabling and then reload your PWA. Then you’ll need to see if you can update your PWA if needed to take advantage of this or get more details on this if the interface is not obvious as you explore audio in the PWA.

I also recommend highly any software from Rogue Amoeba for doing this without needing any PWA change or changing safari features. It hooks directly into the macOS audio processing and unlocks all manner of features not built into the OS.
Note: on Apple silicon-based Macs SoundSource installs a system extension which requires running the OS at "reduced security" level.
